# Q_GADGET has value type semantic?

Tags: qt, qml

From the docs (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#value-types) and other posts I got the impression, that Q_GADGET can be used as a value type with copy semantics.

Let's take the `Actor` from the docs:

```
class Actor
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
public:
    QString name() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(const QString &name) { m_name = name; }

private:
    QString m_name;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Actor)
```

Now I expose an `Actor` with Q_PROPERTY on some C++ object like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(Actor actor READ actor WRITE setActor NOTIFY actorChanged)
```

So far, everything is fine.
Now I have some javascript code in QML (context is the C++ object on which the Q_PROPERTY actor is exposed:

```
{
  var actorCopy = context.actor
  actorCopy.name = "Tom"
}
```

I always assumed that the Actor-Gadget will be copied, when assigning to the javascript variable `actorCopy` and I change the `name` on a copy.
Now I set a breakpoint in the `setActor` function of the defined Q_PROPERTY.
What happens is, when assigning the `name` of the actor in javascript, the `setActor` method will be called.

I would not expect that, since I work on a copy.
My question is, do I have a wrong understanding of Q_GADGET or is this a bug?

I mean, if I would have a O_OBJECT instead of Q_GADGET I would not expect the `setActor` function being called either, since I don't assign the property.
So Q_GADGET is neither a lightweight Q_OBJECT nor a value type.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{
  var actorCopy = context.actor
  var otherCopy = actorCopy
  actorCopy.name = "Tom"
  otherCopy.name = "Gatis"
}
```

Then in your debugger you will see that setName() is called on two different instances. You can print "this" pointer to confirm.

I did not run this code, but I think that is how it should work.

Comment: I did run my code and I think you missed the important and confusing point, that `setActor` is called. This is not about `setName`. IMO `setActor` should only be called, if context.actor is assigned.